# Remmina - top bar does not disappear

Tags: remmina

I am remote logging in from Ubuntu into a windows machine. I am using Remmina. Everything works fine, except for two things:

1. The top bar does not disappear (i have tried pressing the pin highlighted in red)
2. The mouse cursor is definitely too small.

(screenshot below)
[image]

Anyone faced these two isses?